# Creating numpy array from calculations across arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, nodes

I currently have the task of creating a 4x4 array with operations performed on the cells

Below you will see a function that takes in `array` into function `the_matrix` which returns `adj_array`

It then has a for loop that is supposed to loop through `array`, looking at the the cell in `ref_array` and upon finding the matching first two numbers in `array` (like 6,3") it will put that function `lambda N: 30` into it's respective cell in `adj_array`, as it will do for all cells in the 4x4 matrix

Essentially the function should return an array like this

```
array([[inf, <function <lambda> at 0x00000291139AF790>,
<function <lambda> at 0x00000291139AF820>, inf],
[inf, inf, inf, <function <lambda> at 0x00000291139AF8B0>],
[inf, inf, inf, <function <lambda> at 0x00000291139AF940>],
[inf, inf, inf, inf]], dtype=object)
```

My work so far below

```
def the_matrix(array):
  

    ref_array = np.zeros((4,4), dtype = object)
    ref_array[0,0] = (5,0)
    ref_array[0,1] = (5,1)
    ref_array[0,2] = (5,2)
    ref_array[0,3] = (5,3)
    ref_array[1,0] = (6,0)
    ref_array[1,1] = (6,1)
    ref_array[1,2] = (6,2)       
    ref_array[1,3] = (6,3)       
    ref_array[2,0] = (7,0)     
    ref_array[2,1] = (7,1)       
    ref_array[2,2] = (7,2)      
    ref_array[2,3] = (7,3)
    ref_array[3,0] = (8,0)
    ref_array[3,1] = (8,1)
    ref_array[3,2] = (8,2)
    ref_array[3,3] = (8,3)
 
   
    for i in ref_array:
        for a in i: #Expecting to get (5,1) here, but's showing me array
            if a == array[0, 0:2]: #This specific slice was a test
             put the function in that cell for adj_array

    return adj_array

array = np.array([[5, 1, lambda N: 120],
                  [5, 2, lambda N: 30],
                  [6, 3, lambda N: 30],
                  [7, 3, lambda N: N/30]])
```

Have tried variations of this for loop, and it's throwing errors. For one, the `a` in the for loop is displaying the input argument `array`, which is weird because it hasn't been called in the loop at that stage. My intention here is to refer to the exact cell in ref_array.

Not sure where I'm going wrong here and how I'm improperly looping through. Any help appreciated

Comment: Your code is not working. `ref_array` has shape `(4,4)` but you are trying to do `ref_array[5,0]`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang - Sorry, numbers were totally wrong, now updated to suit

Comment: You are trying to place 2-element tuples into scalar elements. Was `ref_array` supposed to be `(4, 4, 2)`?

Comment: It seems that you need a basic tutorial on numpy arrays, which you think are fancy lists

Comment: @Mad Physicist Have now edited the question to be clearer. I do get what you're saying. My current approach is to use `ref_array` as the reference for what values the `lambda` function should be applied to, and `inf` for all others. I presume it's not the right one, but not sure what else I should be doing

Answer (score 1):

Your `ref_array` is object dtype, (4,4) containing tuples:

```
In [26]: ref_array
Out[26]: 
array([[(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)],
       [(6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3)],
       [(7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3)],
       [(8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

Your iteration, just showing the iteration variables.  I'm using `repr

```
In [28]: for i in ref_array:
    ...:     print(repr(i))
    ...:     for a in i:
    ...:         print(repr(a))
    ...: 
array([(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)], dtype=object)
(5, 0)
(5, 1)
(5, 2)
(5, 3)
...
```

So `i` is a "row" of the array, itself a 1d object dtype array.

`a` is one of those objects, a tuple.

Your description of the alternatives is vague.  But assume on tries to start with a numeric dtype array

```
In [30]: arr = np.array(ref_array.tolist())
In [31]: arr
Out[31]: 
array([[[5, 0],
        [5, 1],
        [5, 2],
        [5, 3]],

         ...
        [8, 2],
        [8, 3]]])
In [32]: arr.shape
Out[32]: (4, 4, 2)
```

now the looping:

```
In [33]: for i in arr:
    ...:     print(repr(i))
    ...:     for a in i:
    ...:         print(repr(a))
    ...: 
array([[5, 0],          # i is a (4,2) array
       [5, 1],
       [5, 2],
       [5, 3]])
array([5, 0])           # a is (2,) array....
array([5, 1])
array([5, 2])
array([5, 3])
```

If "the a in the for loop is displaying the input argument array", it's most likely because `a` IS a an array.

Keep in mind that object dtype arrays are processed at list speeds.  You might as well think of them as bastardized lists.  While they have some array enhancements (multidimensonal indexing etc), the elements are still references, and are processed as in lists.

I haven't paid attention as to why you are putting `lambdas` in the array.  It looks ugly, and I don't see what it gains you.  They can't be "evaluated" at array speeds.  You'd have to do some sort of iteration or list comprehension.

### edit

A more direct way of generating the `arr`, derived from `ref_array`:

```
In [39]: I,J = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5,9), np.arange(0,4), indexing='ij')
In [40]: I
Out[40]: 
array([[5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8]])
In [41]: J
Out[41]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
In [42]: arr = np.stack((I,J), axis=2)  # shape (4,4,2)
```

If the function was something like

```
In [46]: def foo(I,J):
    ...:     return I*10 + J
    ...:
```

You could easily generate a value for each pair of the values in `ref_array`.

```
In [47]: foo(I,J)
Out[47]: 
array([[50, 51, 52, 53],
       [60, 61, 62, 63],
       [70, 71, 72, 73],
       [80, 81, 82, 83]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Put simply the issue I'm trying to get my head around is how to  take in `array` into the function and spit out` adj_array` that looks the first bit of code in the question.  Thats all it is, but I think my approach with ref_array is going off the rails with trying to create something to reference as `ref_array` and then finding conditions with the for loop. I just want `the_matrix` function to look at `array` and then broadcast each value to it's respective cell in the 4x4 `adj_array`. I'm getting too deep in the weeds

Comment: You talk in generalities about function and `adj_array`, but really don't show the connection with `ref_array`.